# Button On A Image In HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I was working on this code and could place the button to where I want with a complex code, but I just want to make it more simple. I can now place the button on the image and change its margin-top position but I cannot change its margin-left position. I want each button for the planet but as I said I cannot place it to where the planets are in the picture with a simple code.
Any ideas about where the issue is?

```css
.upfront {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 155px;
  margin-right: 23px;
}

.menu {}

.spaceBoard {
  position: relative;
}

.previews {
  left: 173px;
  position: releative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 215;
  margin-top: 315px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Başlıksız Belge</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body background="https://i.hizliresim.com/DyZ49m.png">
  <script>
    function bgClicked() {
      var id = document.getElementById("bgClicked");
      id.style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("bgMAIN").style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>
  <center>
    <div class="upper"><img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/vJ9n5m.png" width="75%" height="75%" /></div>
    <!--//<div><img src="Pics/2_.png" style="right:9px; top:12 position:relative;" /></div>-->
    <div class="spaceBoard">
      <input type="button" class="button" />
      <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/Eyo5pB.png" id="bgMAIN" onclick="bgClicked()">
      <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/mJB15Z.png" style="visibility:hidden;" class="previews;" id="bgClicked;">
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why two times margin-left and margin-right

Comment: Just a trash code which is there because hard tries for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed px in margin-left below, now it is move as you want

```css
.upfront{
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 155px;
 margin-right: 23px;
}
.menu{
 
}
.spaceBoard{
 position:relative;
 
 
}
.previews{
 left:173px;
 position:releative;

}
.button{
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:215px;
 margin-top:315px;
 z-index:2;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:none; 
}











s
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Başlıksız Belge</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body background="https://i.hizliresim.com/DyZ49m.png">
<script>
 function bgClicked(){
  var id = document.getElementById("bgClicked");
  id.style.visibility="visible";
  document.getElementById("bgMAIN").style.display="none";
 }
 
</script>
 <center>
  <div class="upper"><img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/vJ9n5m.png" width="75%" height="75%"/></div>
        <!--//<div><img src="Pics/2_.png" style="right:9px; top:12 position:relative;" /></div>-->
         <div class="spaceBoard">
        <input type="button" class="button" />
     <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/Eyo5pB.png" id="bgMAIN"  onclick="bgClicked()">
        
  <img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/mJB15Z.png" style="visibility:hidden;"class="previews;" id="bgClicked;">
        
        </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hahah, I have been trying for this for days lmao I was like sure It was working without adding px. Those little details. Thanks man

Comment: @UmutcanBahadır Welcome Mate